# Add class active element in contenteditable

Tags: javascript

I need to add class to this focused element. What I'm trying to do is, detect which row is active, while navigating with `up/down` arrow keys.
 Actually my code does that function, but I don't know how to add class to this focused element.
 Thank you in advance!

Here is a snippet:

```js
var selectedElement = null;
function setFocus(e) {
  if (selectedElement)
    selectedElement.style.outline = 'none';

  selectedElement = window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode;
  selectedElement.style.outline = '1px solid #f00';
};
document.onkeyup = setFocus;
document.onmouseup = setFocus;
```

```css
div:focus { outline: none; }
```

```html
<ul contenteditable="true">
  <li>The first paragraph</li>
  <li>The second paragraph</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why do you tagged it with jQuery? This is pure javascript.

Comment: > A further difference for Mozilla is that once a document is switched to designMode, all events on that particular document are disabled. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38395353/add-class-active-element-in-contenteditable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 selectedElement.className += " active";
```

But don't forget to itarate on each menu items, and remove from the other.